# Не могу понять смысл вопроса

Tags: c++, ооп, классы

Вопрос по С++
"Сколько существует способов создания объектов класса?"

1. Два
2. Один
3. Бесконечное количество
4. В зависимости от версии компилятора С++

---

Я так понимаю, что бесконечное количество. Однако постановка вопроса вдавила меня в сомнения

Comment: ¿Где вы раздобыли такой бестолковый вопрос?

Comment: думаю имелось ввиду на стеке, на куче, статически. но тут как минимум три. Поэтому, я бы ответил, что для старых (до 20 стандарта) один - через конструктор. А сейчас разрешили в некоторых случаях через malloc.

Comment: https://pikabu.ru/story/si_6089148?view=amp :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Объекты класса** всегда создаются единственным образом - с использованием конструктора.

Всё. Других вариантов нет...

Comment: Не всегда. Агрегатная инициализация (`struct A {int x, y;}; A a{4, 5};`) - не вызов конструктора.

Comment: ну так объект считается созданным, когда был вызван конструктор...

Comment: Не всегда @KoVadim `union{ C c1; D d1; } u;` Объект вроде-бы есть. А конструктора не вызвано .... или должен быть????

Comment: теперь уже разрешили и так https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime

Comment: @AlexGlebe Вот тут-то как раз конструктор по умолчанию (для безымянного юниона) вызывается и ничего не делает. Для полей - нет, но они и не существуют как объекты.

Comment: @KoVadim Не понял. Приведите, пожалуйста, пример, когда **объект класса** (в вопросе речь о нем) **создан**, но его **конструктор** (пусть неявно) **не вызван**.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Это можно вполне рассматривать как соптимизированный вызов сгенерированного компилятором конструктора, который конструирует x и y с помощью их конструкторов :)

Comment: в си создать динамическую структуру можно было только через malloc. А в плюсах malloc не создает объект (то есть, он не начинает object lifetime). Поэтому, чисто формально, компилятор может рассматривать такие объекты (а структуры они же почти-почти классы) как не созданные и это большое UB. По факту компиляторы так не делают, так как это сломало бы все. И поэтому было предложение в стандарт, что бы такие варианты считать легитимными. Вот чуть деталей http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0137r1.html

Comment: @Mikhailo Можно рассматривать как что угодно, но это все равно не вызов конструктора. Сравните описание [обычной инициализации](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.general#15.6.2.1) (написано, что конструктор вызывается) и [агрегатной](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.aggr) (про вызов, и тем более генерацию конструкторов - ни слова).